# Add New Node in XML using javascript ActiveXObject give error

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a airport-codes.xml file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<iata>
  <iata_airport_codes>
    <airport>Ocho Rios, Jamaica</airport>
    <code>OCJ</code>
  </iata_airport_codes>
</iata>
```

I want to add node by using javascript i use this code to add node

```
var xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xml.open("GET", "airport-codes.xml", true);
xml.send(null);


var iata_airport_codes = xml.responseXML.createElement("iata_airport_codes");

var airport = xml.responseXML.createElement("airport");
airport.appendChild(xml.responseXML.createTextNode("Mr Njoroge"));

var code = xml.responseXML.createElement("code");
code.appendChild(xml.responseXML.createTextNode("21454741"));

iata_airport_codes.appendChild(airport);
iata_airport_codes.appendChild(code);
xml.responseXML.appendChild(iata_airport_codes);
```

but i got this error :-

**Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to add an element at the top level of the document. You just can add an element in the "iata" node.

So try :

```
xml.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("iata").item(0).appendChild(iata_airport_codes);
```

EDIT : bad syntax in the code

Comment: i try this but its give me this error:- Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName'

Comment: Woups bad syntax, it was : xml.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("iata").item(0).appendChild(iata_airport_codes); but you can try : xml.responseXML.childNodes[0].appendChild(iata_airport_codes);